# Prolog: averages of items in two lists at corresponding indices

Tags: list, prolog, division, addition

I am working on a Prolog program that would take two lists, calculates the average of the elements at the corresponding indices and returns the averages as a list.

This my code. I'm getting `is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` error.

```
sum(H,T,S) :-
   S is H + T.

avelists([],[],_).
avelists([Head|Tail],[Head2|Tail2],[X|Tail3) :-
   X is sum(Head,Head2,A)/2,
   avelists(Tail,Tail2,Tail3).
```

For example:

```
?-  avelists([1,4,3],[3,6,5],Xs]).
Xs = [2,5,4].                          % expected result
```

Why is it not working and giving me that error? It looks to me like it should work.

Comment: You should also fix a syntax error - `avelists([Head|Tail],[Head2|Tail2],[X|Tail3)` is missing a closing bracket `]` in the third list.

Comment: `avelists(As,Bs,Xs) :- findall(M, (nth1(I,As,A),nth1(I,Bs,B),M is (A+B)/2), Xs).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a separate predicate to calculate the sum, you need to evaluate it before using its answer:

```
sum(A, B, Sum), Mean is Sum / 2
```

There is another problem as pointed out [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920534/1812457).

What you actually want:

```
list1_list2_means([], [], []).
list1_list2_means([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [M|Ms]) :-
    M is (X + Y) / 2,
    list1_list2_means(Xs, Ys, Ms).
```

You could also save yourself some typing by writing a helper predicate that finds the mean of two numbers:

```
x_y_mean(X, Y, M) :- M is (X + Y) / 2.
```

Then, you can simply use a `maplist`:

```
?- maplist(x_y_mean, L1, L2, Means).
```

There is no practical benefit from defining a `sum/3` predicate when you can write `(A + B) / 2`. If you did not know how many elements you are going have, you could maybe have something like:

```
numbers_mean(Ns, M) :-
    length(Ns, Len),
    sum_list(Ns, Sum),
    M is Sum / Len.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your base clause has a problem: when you say

```
avelists([],[],_).
```

it means "when two lists are empty, the result is anything". You wanted to say "when two lists are empty, the result is empty", i.e.

```
avelists([],[], []).
```

You should also fix

```
X is sum(Head,Head2,A)/2
```

because you need to use `sum/3` first to compute `A`, and then use `A` to compute `X`.